# Is it true that $End_K (K [x],A) \simeq A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

Suppose $K$ is a field and $A$ is a $K$-algebra. Let $End_K (K [x],A)$ denote the algebra of all endomorphisms from $K [x]$ into $A$. Then by the help of universal property it is very easy to see that there is a one-to-one correspondence $\psi$ between $End_K (K [x],A)$ and $A$ which sends $\phi_a$ to $a$ where for each $a \in A$, $\phi_a$ sends $x$ to $a$ and constants to themselves.But the domain and co-domain of $\psi$ are both algebras.So we may think further and can discuss whether it is an endomorphism or not. Then these two algebras are isomorphic to each other. But I think $\psi$ is not an isomorphism.Are these two algebras isomorphic to each other? If the answer is "yes" then what is this isomorphism?

Please help me in this regard. I am in a fix.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These are not endomorphisms, I presume you mean homomorphisms.

Comment: Yeah you have rightly judged.

Comment: Well, you need to check that your map is linear, in other words $\phi \mapsto \phi(X)$ is linear. But this is obvious by definition isn't it?
Maybe I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Do we not need to check whether $\psi (\phi_a + \phi_b) = \psi (\phi_a)+ \psi (\phi_b) $, $\psi (\phi_a \phi_b) = \psi (\phi_a) \psi (\phi _b)$ and $\psi (c \phi_a) = c \psi ( \phi_a)$ for all $a,b \in A$ and for all $c \in K$ for algebra homomorphism?

Comment: But then we should have $f (a+b) = f (a) + f (b), f (ab) = f (a)f (b)$ and $f (ca) = c f (a)$ for all $f (x) \in K [x]$, for all $a,b \in A$ and for all $c \in K$.

Comment: I’m going to de-predicialize the situation by calling the set of $K$-algebra morphisms from $B$ to $A$ by the nonstandard name $\text{Morph}_K(B,A)$. I think that the one-dimensionality of the situation had led to a bit of confusion. You should be able to show that the *set* $\text{Morph}_K(K[x,y,z],A)$ is in natural one-to-one correspondence with the *set* $A\times A\times A$, just the three-fold set-theoretic product. We *do not* expect that this one-to-one correspondence is any kind of ring homomorphism.

Comment: How are you making $\operatorname{Hom}(K[x],A)$ a ring?